# Render Error: Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'Contacts'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm starting my studies in React Native and I'm having problems using navigation.

And this error always appears Rander Error: Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'Contacts' :[Screenshot Render Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg67d.png)

Here is the code:
**Contacts.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class Contacts extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>CONTACTS</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default Contacts;
```

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Contacts from './src/pages/Contacts/index';
import Information from './src/pages/Information/index';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App(){
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="Contacts" 
          component={Contacts}/>
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="Information" 
          component={Information}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Furthermore, I have already tried several ways:
**Contacts.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import {View, Text} from 'react-native'

export default function Information(){
    return(
        <View>
            <Text> INFORMATION </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: It is problem with the import or export for you. Please share your folder structure also. According to what I can see it must be `import Contacts from './src/pages/Contacts';`